# How to insert the picture to the right of this text?

Tags: graphics

I would like to insert the below image in the right of the text. Just as in the below picture:

[image]

The image I would like to insert is

[image]

The sample code of my LaTex is

```
%
\documentclass{beamer}
\usecolortheme{beaver}
\usefonttheme{structurebold}
\title{Project 1: EM algorithm}

\usepackage{parskip,listings,dsfont,bbm,geometry,parskip,xcolor,latexsym}
\usepackage{graphicx,amsmath,amssymb,mathtools,amsthm,array,wrapfig}

\begin{document}



\frame{
\frametitle{Single Imputation by \textbf{ImputeTestData} package}

With \textbf{ImputeTestData} package, method EM is used:

\begin{itemize}
\item Execution time: $28.93$ sec
\item Estimated bias : $-2.217083e -03$
\item Estimated variance: $2.179828e -07$
\end{itemize}

However, all filled missing values are rounded so we have the same results for both default setting or add prior from complete data.

If we use $waget$ instead $lwaget$, the result is different and better for data set using the prior data.}

\end{document}
```

Could you please help me insert the picture to the right of the text in LaTex?

Thank you so much!

Comment: You could try to use the [multicol](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/multicol?lang=en) package or the [wrapfig](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/wrapfig) one

Comment: Ah wait a sec. You're using `beamer`...

Comment: You would like to insert the three sizes together??

Comment: Hi @Bernard, it's a whole image :)

Comment: I understand you've posted three images in a single one, but in the real frame?

Comment: @Bernard, I don't understand what you meant by "real frame". Grouping three images this way is not good, but my professor set a limit of the number of slides :(

Comment: Well, two of these images are the same at different scales, so I was puzzled.

Comment: Thank you so much @Bernard, you help me save some space in the slide :)